# How to get browser history on android version > 23 programmatically?

Tags: android, browser

As we can see browser API is removed from android version > 23, so is there any other method to get browser history with user's permission? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this problem? Please let me know. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar: Did you find any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the cited documentation, com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS is still defined by the framework, and can still be obtained by apps. Unfortunately, on Marshmallow and later, Chrome checks for a different permission, one that regular apps aren't allowed to obtain. For compatibility reasons, when that permission check inevitably fails, Chrome returns zero rows instead of throwing a SecurityException.

You can see the source code here:

query() calls hasReadAccess(), which calls hasPermission("com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"), which on API >= M ignores the permission argument and instead checks for com.android.chrome.permission.READ_WRITE_BOOKMARK_FOLDERS. This permission is limited to system apps and apps signed with Google's key.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I want to get browser history/bookmarks on android phone for some application, how can I get it?

Comment: @shaik subhani: Long story short, do you mean to say post Android 7.0, there is no way an app can access users browsing history? Am in need of the same too.